# Дерегистрация микросервиса в zookeeper (Spring)

Tags: spring-boot

я начинающий Spring-разработчик и хотел разобраться с регистрацией микросервисов на Zookeper.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient()
public class ZookeeperhelloworldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZookeeperhelloworldApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

На самом кипере регистрация в ветке service проходит удачно и вроде бы всё гуд, но есть одно но... При остановки сервиса, дерегистраци (а именно удаление записи о реге) проходит с задержкой в секунд 10-15, что очень не хорошо. Можно ли сократить этот промежуток? Может какой @Predestroy метод нужен?